# `SFDC_STACK_DEPTH` header being added to callouts

Tags: callout, header

I have a callout that retrieves information from an external rest API.  We  randomly started getting a bunch of failures:

> client sent invalid header line: "SFDC_STACK_DEPTH: 1" while reading
>   client request headers

Does anyone know why `SFDC_STACK_DEPTH: 1` would have been set?  I can't seem to find any documentation on it.

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/115031/where-can-i-find-the-header-information-in-a-webservice-callout-request - I believe it is added automatically. Maybe to protect class made from SF to SF but that is just a guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SFDC_STACK_DEPTH` header is automatically added  by any request that is made from a Salesforce server.

It is used to prevent chaining of requests from one Salesforce server to another. Without such a mechanism threads could get blocked as they wait for other threads to complete. You could do things like chaining one anonymous Apex execution to another to work around other limits. So while you can make one level of calls from Salesforce to Salesforce, any further attempts will get blocked by the presence of the header.

See also:

- [Callout loop not allowed error](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/6142/102)

Comment: Yea. That's what I was thinking lol.

Comment: awesome,  Not sure why the service randomly started throwing that error if this header is always present.  Something else must have triggered the failure. 
 Thanks as always